# Using the MVVM for searching

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, search, mvvm

well, I am building an App, which searches a DB for a given query and which downloads its results afterwards, to show them in a listbox at the mainpage.

Every result has even more details to go to and so the first thing I decided to use is some kind of a details page. But I don't know how to realize this process:

- On MainPage, fill out textbox and press button to search
- Somehow go to to MainViewModel and invoke the LoadData() method with the value of MainPage's textbox

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel

```
    public class SearchViewModel {
      public ICommand SearchCommand {get;set;}
      public string SearchCriteria {get;set;}
    }
```

in view codebehind

```
    View.DataContext = viewModel
```

View xaml:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchCriteria}"/>
```

When command is invoked filter data by search criteria notify view.

Here is description of MVVM patter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Comment: I don't exactly undestand what you mean here

Comment: MVVM is Model View and ViewModel, Model is your data, View is UI, ViewModel is a class to which View binded

Comment: Yes, but what "View" do you mean with View.DataContext?

Comment: View is your window or usercontrol. For simplicity you can place this.DataContext = viewModel into load method.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that MVVM is: Model, View & View Model.

So you have the search on the main page (view) that triggers the code in that page's view model. You then display the detail in a new view, so really what you should be thinking is:

1. How do I pass parameters from one view model to another view model. This will depend on your MVVM framework so can't give you specifics since you haven't stated what framework.
2. Then use the search in your model (you neglect it in your question) using the parameter.

What I do with my MVVM system is do a standard page navigate and pass the parameter to the new page, then I grab that in the OnNavigated method and parse it out and pass it to the view model which then filters the data in the model with that value.

Comment: What is meant by ViewModel? The XAML?

Comment: @Clue it's probably better that you do some reading about what MVVM is before you begin your application. How can you follow a pattern if you don't understand what at least 1/3 of the pieces are?

Comment: @Clue your view is the XAML, the code that is bound to it is the ViewModel (VM). The VM generally talks to a Model which is separate code that handles the talking to databases etc... The idea is that the model is the data structure, but often that data structure doesn't fit what you want to display so you have a middle layer that understand the model and takes that data and puts it into a structure that is the best representation for the view to use. It does sound like you only have a model & view in your code, which is why this is tough to solve for you.

Comment: It's not about understanding the model, it's about going for the practical reality. I see that XAML is View, *.CS is Model. The ViewModel is as far as I got it the pieces inside a *.CS that handle with the XAML.

Comment: @Clue, the each piece of the pattern isn't specifically assigned file types, it's a logical "separation of concerns". The view is your presentation layer (it's only concerned with what you see on screen, and handling logic to do so). The model is data that you intend to work with. The view model is a class (just another .cs file in your words) that is the glue between the other 2. It is what binds to the view (lookup "Binding") to display data. It would also be the entity that connects to services to retrieve data.

Comment: @Clue "It's not about understanding the model, it's about going for the practical reality" - I agree with you but then you shouldn't use the pattern name in your question. You have driven the discussion that way because of your choice of words.